# Nginx Vhosts with SSL

Tags: nginx, ssl, redirect, sni, 301-redirect

I have 3 domains running on an nginx server with ssl

domain.pw 
domain.info 
domain.mobi

i have sni enabled, and am using a vhost for each site.

the host records for the site are all like this

```
A Record: @ <IP ADDRESS> 1800
A Record: www <IP ADDRESS> 1800
```

the conf files are all like this. and do their job as intended pretty much except one problem(i'll expand on this in a moment, now i will explain the configuration file you see below)

step 1 `server_name` (the first comment) redirects www traffic to non-www

step 2 `server_name` redirects http:// traffic on port 80 to https://

step 3 `server_name` is the actual server code for serving pages over ssl from port 443.

```
log_format  www.domain.pw  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
             '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
             '"$http_user_agent" $http_x_forwarded_for';

#redirects www traffic to domain.pw

server {
    server_name  www.domain.pw;
    rewrite ^(.*) https://domain.pw$1 permanent;
}

#redirect http traffic to https
server {
        listen   80;
        server_name domain.pw;
        return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

#server and ssl configuration.       
server {
        listen   443;
        server_name domain.pw;
        index index.php;
        root  /home/wwwroot/www.domain.pw;
        ssl on;
        #enables SSLv3/TLSv1, but not SSLv2 which is weak and should no longer be used.
        ssl_protocols SSLv3 TLSv1.2;
        #Disables all weak ciphers
        ssl_ciphers ALL:!aNULL:!ADH:!eNULL:!LOW:!EXP:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM;
        ssl_certificate /usr/local/nginx/ssl/domains/domain.pw.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /usr/local/nginx/ssl/domains/domain.pw.pem;

        include other.conf;
        location ~ .*\.(php|php5)?$
            {
                try_files $uri =404;
                fastcgi_pass  unix:/tmp/php-cgi.sock;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                include fcgi.conf;
            } 
        location ~ .*\.(gif|jpg|jpeg|png|bmp|swf)$
            {
                expires      30d;
            }

        location ~ .*\.(js|css)?$
            {
                expires      12h;
            }



        access_log  /home/wwwlogs/www.domain.pw.log  www.domain.pw;
        error_page   404  =  /access_denied.php;
        error_page   403  =  /access_denied.php;
}
```

**the problem**

`www.domain.info` redirects to `https://domain.info`

`www.domain.mobi` redirects to `https://domain.mobi`

`www.domain.pw` redirects to `https://domain.info` **<<< Doh! wtf??? >>>**

**Note**: this problem only exists with `www` the redirect works fine with out it.

please help, this thing has been bugging me for days, i've jumbled my configuration files around rebooted my server, reissued my ssl certificates, and no matter what it always results in error. why?

Answer (score 0):

Your HTTP to HTTPS redirect is subtly wrong:

```
        return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
```

This uses the server name defined in the `server` block, which is probably not what you want, especially when you are using a single `server` block to redirect several domains.

Instead, use:

```
        return 301 https://$http_host$request_uri;
```

Which will use the domain provided by the client.

Comment: ok, thanks i will try it and report back results. appreciate you taking the time to help a n00b.. edit: Negative ghost rider. applied your suggestion and rebooted the server. still redirects to the wrong website, but only on `www` EDIT EDIT: I will add that i am using multiple config files in the folder \vhost\ for each site. should i perhaps try setting up ssl over a different port for each site?

Comment: though it seems odd that an issue would arise with a certificate installed prior to the other two domains/certificates being purchased, i will make a new key, generate a new csr and start the reissue process to see if that clears up the issue.

Comment: Why are you reissuing SSL certificates? The problem you described doesn't have any relevance to them.

Comment: because i'm attempting to solve my own problem.